# Update a listview from modify on selected items

Tags: c#, listview, observablecollection

Excuse me if I didn't formulate good the question, but don't know how to name it better...

I have a project with some ListView, binded to ObservableCollection.
When I make a right click on my ListView, to change name, or other parameter, the ListView doesn't automatically refresh until I go out, then open again.

Here is my behind code for context :

```
public class Contexte : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private Affaire affaireSelectionnee;
        public Affaire AffaireSelectionnee
        {
            get { return affaireSelectionnee; }
            set
            {
                if (value == affaireSelectionnee) return;
                affaireSelectionnee = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AffaireSelectionnee");
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Affaire> listeDesAffairesSelectionnees;
        public ObservableCollection<Affaire> ListeDesAffairesSelectionnees
        {
            get { return listeDesAffairesSelectionnees; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesAffairesSelectionnees, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Phase> listeDesPhasesSelectionnees;
        public ObservableCollection<Phase> ListeDesPhasesSelectionnees
        {
            get { return listeDesPhasesSelectionnees; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesPhasesSelectionnees, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Assemblage> listeDesAssemblagesSelectionnees;
        public ObservableCollection<Assemblage> ListeDesAssemblagesSelectionnees
        {
            get { return listeDesAssemblagesSelectionnees; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesAssemblagesSelectionnees, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Repere> listeDesReperesSelectionnees;
        public ObservableCollection<Repere> ListeDesReperesSelectionnees
        {
            get { return listeDesReperesSelectionnees; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesReperesSelectionnees, value); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Affaire> listeDesAffaires;
        public ObservableCollection<Affaire> ListeDesAffaires
        {
            get { return listeDesAffaires; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesAffaires, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Phase> listeDesPhases;
        public ObservableCollection<Phase> ListeDesPhases
        {
            get { return listeDesPhases; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesPhases, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Assemblage> listeDesAssemblages;
        public ObservableCollection<Assemblage> ListeDesAssemblages
        {
            get { return listeDesAssemblages; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesAssemblages, value); }
        }
        private ObservableCollection<Repere> listeDesReperes;
        public ObservableCollection<Repere> ListeDesReperes
        {
            get { return listeDesReperes; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesReperes, value); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string nomPropriete)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nomPropriete));
        }

        private bool NotifyPropertyChanged<T>(ref T variable, T valeur, [CallerMemberName] string nomPropriete = null)
        {
            if (object.Equals(variable, valeur)) return false;

            variable = valeur;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nomPropriete);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

I load the context once when loading the programm :

```
DBConnect DataBase = new DBConnect();
string requete = "SELECT * FROM affaire ORDER BY ID";
List<Affaire> liste = DataBase.Select_affaire(requete, true);
contexte = new Contexte { ListeDesAffaires = new ObservableCollection<Affaire>(liste), ListeDesPhases = new ObservableCollection<Phase>(), ListeDesAssemblages = new ObservableCollection<Assemblage>(), ListeDesReperes = new ObservableCollection<Repere>(), AffaireSelectionnee = new Affaire(), ListeDesAffairesSelectionnees = new ObservableCollection<Affaire>(liste), ListeDesPhasesSelectionnees = new ObservableCollection<Phase>(), ListeDesAssemblagesSelectionnees = new ObservableCollection<Assemblage>(), ListeDesReperesSelectionnees = new ObservableCollection<Repere>() };
DataContext = contexte;
```

Then my function that may update property :

```
foreach (Phase ph in contexte.ListeDesPhasesSelectionnees)
{
  Phase ph_find = contexte.ListeDesPhases.First(s=>s==ph);
  ph_find.Priorite = new_priorite;
}
```

ph_find.Priorite is well updated, as is my Observable Collection "contexte.ListeDesPhases", but no refresh is made on the ListView.

**Edit** : Well I could solve the problem adding a ListView1.Items.Refresh()...
I am not sure this is the most correct way(is not bidding supposed to refresh the listview automaticaly?), but for now it works

**Edit2** :

My XAML code (ListView of the phase) :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView2" ItemsSource="{Binding ListeDesPhases}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick" GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged" >

            <ListView.View>

                <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" x:Name="GridView2">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" Header="ID" Width="50"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding= "{Binding NomPhase}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Nom}" Width="200"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IdAffaire}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.IdAffaire}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CommPhase}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Commentaire}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Priorite}" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Priorite}" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

My Phase class :

```
public class Phase
    {
        public string NomPhase { get; set; }
        public long IdAffaire { get; set; }
        public string CommPhase { get; set; }
        public int Priorite { get; set; }
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public List<Assemblage> ListAssemblages { get; set; }
        public Phase()
        {
            this.NomPhase = "";
            this.IdAffaire = 0;
            this.CommPhase = "";
            this.Priorite = 0;
            this.ID = 0;
            this.ListAssemblages = new List<Assemblage>();
        }
        ...
    }
```

**Edit3** :

Tried to modify as indicated by Netstep, but still the same :

```
public ObservableCollection<Phase> ListeDesPhases
        {
            get { return listeDesPhases; }
            set { NotifyPropertyChanged(ref listeDesPhases, value);
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Priorite");
            }
        }
```

**Edit 4** :

Well, I now understand that nothing was happening, I read that course http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/ to understand it...
So example given by NetStep was the good one (just didn't understand what is the `RaisePropertyChanged(() => Priorite);` part? Is this due to the use of mvvmlight.net library?

```
public class Phase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string nomPhase;
        public string NomPhase
        {
            get { return this.nomPhase; }
            set
            {
                if (this.nomPhase != value)
                {
                    this.nomPhase = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("NomPhase");
                }
            }
        }
        private int priorite;
        public int Priorite
        {
            get { return this.priorite; }
            set
            {
                if (this.priorite != value)
                {
                    this.priorite = value;
                    this.NotifyPropertyChanged("Priorite");
                }
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    ...//all of my other functions
    }
```

So this is what I did and it works good now.

Then I have the following question : I have 4 different objects displayed in 4 ListView(Contract, Subcontract, Phase and Detail).
Contract is the "Mother Class", it countains parameters, but also contains a list of Subcontracts. Subcontracts contains several parameters, and a list of Phases, and each Phase contains some parameters, with a list of Details.
Each of them is displayed in a different ListView(4 ListView).
May I define 4 different ObservableCollection, or is there a way to define only one ObservableCollection for all the "tree", then bind on parameters of my ObservableCollection>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the field properly updated in UI, please ensure that Phase class also implement INotifyPropertyChanged someway and call

```
NotifyPropertyChanged("Priorite")
```

in set accessor. Just using the ObservableCollection is not enough, it handles notifying only Add/Remove operations. And you right - ListView1.Items.Refresh() is a workaround in this case. 
Hope this will help, otherwise please share Phase class code and your xaml code to get more clear comment/answer.

Here is the example, based on MVVM light library:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Phase : ViewModelBase
    {
        private int _priorite;

        public int Priorite
        {
            get { return _priorite; }
            set
            {
                _priorite = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Priorite);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the rest of code can remain unchanged. You also can inherit you Context class from ViewModelBase

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you mean I may add a "NotifyPropertyChanged" for each of the properties of my class that I display?
And why do you ask for the Phase class? I defined all of my ObservableCollections in a separate Context class (or is this also a bad mode to work). I am completely new in using ObservableCollection so I don't know good how to structure it...

Comment: Also, my foreach (Phase ph in contexte.ListeDesPhasesSelectionnees), is it the most "optimal" way to do it, or is there a way to do something like "contexte.ListeDesPhases.Find(s=>s==ListeDesPhasesSelectionnees) to return the list of all selected items at once, didn't find anything about it.
Also wondering if I do good to make 2 different ObservableCollection, one for all the list, one for selected items... I just need the selected items when I select one item(if selectedItems.Count==1), to display the value in a textbox.

Comment: Understand better why Class is needed... I read a lot about it, but it seems much harder than just bind for adding/removing objects from list. If you could give me example how to modify class for "Property" value, I could do it for remaining properties(For now didn't manage to do it).

Comment: At first, it's better to define a base class for all view models that will implement NotifyPropertyChanged, or, even better, to use MVVM library, like  http://www.mvvmlight.net/, for example, and inherit all view models from base class ViewModelBase - I will edit my answer and will add an example

Comment: For the Class "Phase : ViewModelBase", may I modify my class I made already, or may this be part of the context class?Because my Phase class has a lot of functions that doesn't interact with view, and if I understood good, the ViewModel may be separated from the rest of the code.

Comment: Well, I could find a course about it : http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/responding-to-changes/ So I needed to modify my Class(I believed it was made separately)... Then I update my question, because I have a new question linked to that, thanks

Comment: >ViewModel may be separated - yes it should be separated, in general, but it's up to developer: if you feel that View Models are just duplicate Model fields, then it might be possible to have one class

Comment: >May I define 4 different ObservableCollection, or is there a way to define only one ObservableCollection for all the "tree":

Comment: for my part I defined 4 ObservableCollection, but I meet problems to update changes to "Mother" ObservableCollection. I made a post more "clear" I guess, if you could have a look, thanks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47748369/cascade-binding-on-observablecollection-containing-other-observablecollection

Comment: If you have different types, then each should be placed in it's own field: class Contract will have a list of Subsontracts and so on. If you plan to Add/Remove items interactively, then use ObservableCollection<T>, otherwise you can use regular List<T>

Comment: Ok - will look to that question

Comment: I use ObservableCollection<T>, but the problem is when I add/Remove sub-contracts, they are not added/removed in my in my ObservableCollection<Contract>. For now only solution I found is add them in both ObservableCollection. Not such a big problem, but I guess there is a way to do it in automatic?

Comment: This might be because you define all collections inside the Contexte class, but it's not neccessary, you can have normal master-detail relations and bind to nested collections using path, for example: "ItemsSource={Binding SelectedContract.SubContracts}

Comment: yes in fact I believed that defining 4 different collections for the same thing (the contract) was not very nice, but didn't know that about this trick to link selectedItem, I think the example you gave me will help... just bad I need to go make documents, so only later will try it :) And how would you advise me to edit/remove/add the "Phase" Items? for now I see only one solution doing SelectedAffaire.ListeDesPhases.Remove(selectedPhase)

Comment: yes, this is how to do that, but you need to select it first, like this: SelectedAffaire.ListeDesPhases.Remove(SelectedPhase)